# How to transmit data using GFSK modulation?

Tags: gnuradio

I am new to this domain. 
I want to transmit data using `GFSK` modulation using GNU Radio which response to the following specifications :

- Deviation : +/-2,4 kHz +0,2%
- Modulation index : 2
- Filter index : 0.5 BT
- Bitrate : 2400 bit/s

I want to transmit this data (data is in `HEXA`):
Preamble : 55 55

- Synchro : F6 72
- L-field ( data + CRC) : 20

Comment: The question as you're asking it is too vague. What have you tried? Where did you encounter problems? If you haven't, please read http://tutorials.gnuradio.org

Comment: thank you for your response i will check the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have based on this example of FSK transmitter, https://nccgroup.github.io/RFTM/fsk_transmitter.html
so you need juste to put the value of BT equal to 0.5 to make a GFSK transmitter. And everthing works correctely.

Answer (score 0):

Please start with the gr-digital (part of GNU Radio dist) `GFSK Mod` block. Take a peek at the source python, and then you'll want to look at the gr-analog `frequency_modulation.h` source for details about FM, specifically frequency deviation. For some reason, the doxygen output does not generate the embedded formula, which is why looking at the header file is suggested.

Then I suggest you do some simple experiments in GNU Radio Companion to better understand the `GFSK Mod` block.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have developed a successful example after surfing in the net